# Resharper adding a lot of spaces between method parameter type and name

Tags: c#, visual-studio, formatting, resharper

Given the following code:

```
internal interface IMyInterface
{
    bool MethodOne(string parameter);
    bool AVeryVeryVeryVeryVeryLongMethodName(string myParameter);
}
 
internal class MyClass : IMyInterface
{

}
```

I let Resharper implement the missing members from the interface into `MyClass`:
[image]

This ends up with many spaces between parameter type and name for `MethodOne`,highlighted in yellow:
[image]

How can I configure Resharper to get rid of this spacing? What I want to have is this:

[image]

Comment: Have you seen Options > Code Editing > C# > Spaces?

Comment: Maybe it's the `Options | Code Editing | C# | Formatting Style | Tabs, Indents, Alignment | Align similar code in columns | Simple methods, operators, delegates` setting?

Comment: thanks for your comments, I could find a matching setting, see my reply below.

Answer (score 1):

For me disabling `Code Editing - C# - Formatting Style - Tabs, Indents, Alignment - Align similar code in columns -> Multiline method signature` worked to fix this, even though it's not a multiline method signature

Comment: Hi, thanks for noticing! I've filed a bug report - https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-495964/.